# I don't know difference between two codes in colab

Tags: python

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3])
y=np.array([4,5,6])
np.dot(x.T,y)
```

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
y=np.array([[4],[5],[6]])
np.dot(x.T,y)
```

In first case, answer is just 32, integer.
But, in second case, answer is array([[32]])

I think two codes are similar. What is diffence?

Comment: they are not, the shapes are different.

Answer (score 0):

you obtain two different results because the shape of the two arrays are different. Indeed in the first case the shape o x is (3,) , while in the second case the shape of x is (3,1).

You can verify this by typing:

```
x.shape
```

x and y are two array either in the first or in the second case but they dimensions change in the two cases.